# Array of objects within object

Tags: javascript

I try to get an array of objects within parent object.
The parent object is created before xmlHttpRequest, then i fill the result of my xmlHttpRequest within my object. That create in my object an array of my results (array of children objects)

console.log(obj):

```
Object [...]
  0: Array [{...}, {...}, {...}, ...]
    0: Object {id: "1", name: "application1", version: "1.0", ...}
    1: Object {id: "2", name: "application2", version: "1.0", ...}
    2: Object {id: "3", name: "application3", version: "1.0", ...}
    ...
```

The problem is that i can't read my children objects

console.log(obj[0]):

```
Array []
  length: 0
  __proto__: Array []
```

But i expected to get that:

```
Array [{...}, {...}, ...]
  0: Object {id: "1", name: "application1", version: "1.0", ...}
  1: Object {id: "2", name: "application2", version: "1.0", ...}
  2: Object {id: "3", name: "application3", version: "1.0", ...}
  ...
```

Details of my code:

```
var res = {0:[]};
var Carmin = new CarminClient(url)

Carmin.listPipelines(function (data) {
        res[0] = data;
    });

console.log(res); // Filled
console.log(res[0]); // Empty
```

I hope to someone can help me :)

Comment: You need to show the code you've written to get these results, chances are you're doing it before the array is populated because the request is async.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I have edited my topic. I fill correctly my variable when the request is finished.

Comment: The log of `res` updates in run time, you can see `i` there. Check the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) for more

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `xmlHttpRequest` is asynchronous.

When your initial `console.log(res)` is being it, it is "Filled" as it has a key (`0`) with a value of `[]`. Also, if you're looking at this in the google dev tools it could be filled after the fact.

If you change it to

```
var res = {0:[]};
var Carmin = new CarminClient(url)

Carmin.listPipelines(function (data) {
        res[0] = data;

        console.log(res[0]); // <---
    });
```

You will see your data.

The function you pass to `Carmin.listPipelines` is called a `callback` and is what will run when your have access to the data. You can't do anything else with the data until this function has been called.

With newer Javascript versions you can convert your code into async / await with something like:

```
async function myFunction () {
  var Carmin = new CarminClient(url);
  var data = await Carmin.listPipelines();
  console.log(data);
}
```

This lets you write async "synchronous looking" code